# Every time r starts it reads this error message in the GUI: Error: could not find function "libPaths"

Tags: r

Every time I start R I get this error message in the GUI: Error: could not find function "libPaths". This is wrong as the correct function is ".libPaths"

I shouldn't get this error message at all when starting R but ever since I have I find that dada2 from Bioconductor has entirely stopped working

Comment: Do you have a `.Rprofile` set up to run code at startup?

Comment: I have an .Rprofile and I have where I want packages to go listed in it but outside this, I am not sure what else needs to be in .Rprofile for it to work

Comment: Well, what's the contents of that file? Normally code doesn't automatically run at startup. So if an error is popping up, it probably has something to do with the contents of `.Rprofile`.

Comment: this is the contents of my .Rprofile: libPaths('C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.0/library')

Comment: So you are missing a `.` in front of `libPaths` in your `.Rprofile`. So you are trying to run a function that doesn't exist just as the error message said. You need to change that to `.libPaths('C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.0/library')` though I'm surprised that's not one of the default locations already. Not sure why you would need that.

Comment: Do you know what the default location supposed to be called? R was downloading packages to my onedrive so I tried to change that but it ended up messing up the software on my computer.

Comment: I uninstalled R and reinstalled it and got the program to start working again